# Athena Partition Projection Not Working As Expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am moving from registered partitions to partition projection.

Previously my data was partitioned by `p_year={yyyy}/p_month={MM}/p_day={dd}/p_hour={HH}/...` and I am moving these to `p_date={yyyy}-{MM}-{dd} {HH}:00:00/..`

I have a recent events table that stores the last 2 days worth of events. And so my `p_date` range is `NOW-2DAYS,NOW`. The full table parameters are-

```
projection.enabled: 'True'
projection.p_date.type: 'date'
projection.p_date.range: NOW-2DAYS,NOW
projection.p_date.format: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
projection.p_date.interval: 1
projection.p_date.interval.unit: 'HOURS'
```

But when I try to query this, I get no results.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM recent_events_2d_v2
> 0
```

However, If I change the date range to `2020-09-01 00:00:00,NOW` I do get results.

Something seems off with the relative date ranges with partition projection. Can anyone see what I may be doing wrong, or is this a bug?

Comment: Did you try a longer relative range? Like NOW-2YEARS ? Or using quotation marks around `NOW-2DAYS,NOW`

Comment: Yes- the time range is valid, so making this `2YEARS` doesn't help. Adding quotations also causes a parsing exception `GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR: Text ''NOW-2YEARS'' could not be parsed at index 0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your date format to `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:\'00:00\''` (i.e. literal "00:00" instead of minutes and seconds placeholders).

The way partition projection deals with dates leaves some things to be desired. It seems reasonable that if you say the interval is one hour that the timestamps get rounded to the nearest hour, but that's not what happens. Athena will use the actual "now" to generate the partition values, and if your date format contains fields for minutes and seconds, those will be filled in too.

I assume the reason why it worked when you used a hard coded timestamp is that Athena uses that value as the seed for the sequence, and all other timestamps will also be aligned to the hour.

Answer (score -3):

If you are sure your bucket `p_date={yyyy}-{MM}-{dd} {HH}:00:00/..` contains data, then you need to make sure that partitions are correctly loaded. Try running

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE recent_events_2d_v2
```

and rerun the query.

Comment: I'm using partition projection (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection.html) so i shouldn't need to load the partitions.

Comment: I am also sure there is data in there because in my original post I mentioned I was able to get data when I changed the projection range from `NOW-2DAYS` to a set datetime

Comment: Your set datetime-range is different from your relative range. Can you try setting the set datetime-range such that it's equal to the relative?